# array doesn't iterate value just array name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know this is basic but, I'm trying to iterate the contents of an array that is chosen randomly. This javascript returns the random array's name but doesn't list its content. Any help would be useful.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var intros = ['introOne', 'introTwo'];

var opening = intros[Math.floor(Math.random() * intros.length)];

var introOne = [
    '<img src="assets/redOne.jpg">',
    '<img src="assets/redTwo.jpg">',
    '<img src="assets/redThree.jpg>'];

var introTwo = [
  '<img src="assets/rblueOne.jpg">',
    '<img src="assets/rblueTwo.jpg">',
    '<img src="assets/blueThree.jpg>'];


for (var i=0; i<opening.length; i++) {
  document.write(opening[i]);


}

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote the array names when you reference them.

```js
var introOne = [
  '<img src="assets/redOne.jpg">',
  '<img src="assets/redTwo.jpg">',
  '<img src="assets/redThree.jpg">'
];

var introTwo = [
  '<img src="assets/rblueOne.jpg">',
  '<img src="assets/rblueTwo.jpg">',
  '<img src="assets/blueThree.jpg">'
];

var intros = [introOne, introTwo];

var opening = intros[Math.floor(Math.random() * intros.length)];

for (var i = 0; i < opening.length; i++) {
  document.write(opening[i]);
}
```